# Make an app (OSX) be able to be used in "open with" submenu

Tags: macos

I made an application with Unity for OSX to open and modify images. Now, I want to be able able to open a file with it by using "open with". I managed to make the app appear in that submenu, but it won't open : I get an error from the os saying my app can't open the file. I really don't know why, I have no background whatsoever in OSX, and I didn't find any help on the web.

My goal is to retrieve the path of that file looking into the command line's arguments.

This is how the info.plist looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>StereoMacBuild</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>Unity Player version 2017.3.1f1 (fc1d3344e6ea). (c) 2018 Unity Technologies ApS. All rights reserved.</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>PlayerIcon.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.Company.ProductName</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>MacOSX</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string>public.app-category.games</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>StereoProto</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>PlayerApplication</string>
    <key>UnityBuildNumber</key>
    <string>fc1d3344e6ea</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.9.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Thanks to anyone taking some time to help me !